# How to find the OR of Active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
[#<ModelName:0x00000008c03b38
  id: 52905,
  sunday: true,
  monday: true,
  tuesday: true,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: false,
  friday: false,
  saturday: false>,
 #<ModelName:0x00000008c039f8
  id: 52907,
  sunday: false,
  monday: false,
  tuesday: false,
  wednesday: true,
  thursday: true,
  friday: true,
  saturday: true>]
```

This is the object I have, now the output should be in such a way that .. if sunday is true in atleast one of the two .. sunday should be true. I know looping is a solution but I feel it's expensive. Is there any other way?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense(atleast to me). Are you only interested in comparing two objects? If yes, why would you need a loop? Please improve your question so that everyone can understand.

Comment: It can be more than two ... oops .. sorry

Comment: Suppose I need to give the whole aggreggation sunday: true, monday: true .. I cannot run 7 queries .. like objects.where(sunday: true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will pluck all the `sunday` boolean values and do an `or` operation on them, it will return `true` even if one `sunday` is `true` in the array

```
ModelName.pluck(:sunday).inject(:|)
```

Hope that helps!